# Derivative at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Prove that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, &x \notin \mathbb{Q} \\ 
x^2, & x \in \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

has a derivative at $0$

*The derivative exists if the limit*

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \text{ exists} $$

***For $x \in \mathbb{Q}$:***

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}= \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^2-0}{x}=0$$

Now I have to find that this limit is $0$ if $x \notin\mathbb Q$ right?

How do I prove that?

Comment: You have written $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb Q$ in the function definition. Also, note that $f(x) \leq x^2$, so you can try to use squeeze theorem with the limit.

Comment: That is correct. And if $x\notin\mathbb Q,$ then finding the limit is even easier.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more? I still have some trouble with it

Answer (score 0):

With $\epsilon, \delta:$

$x \in \mathbb{R}$.

We show that $f'(0)$ exists and $f'(0)=0$.

Since $f(0)=0$, we have for real $x$:

$|\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}| \le |\dfrac{x^2}{x}|=|x|.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ given.

Choose $\delta = \epsilon$ , then

$|x| \lt \delta$ implies

$|\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-0| \le |x| \lt \epsilon,$.